# How to fetch Restricted data in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating an app in which I fetch the data using xml parser. The result is in string form so I store the value of regID in a NSString variable val. Now I want to check if self.val is greater then 0 then user navigate to other page.

```
 if ([self.val isEqual:@"0"]) {
        NSLog(@"value of string is 0 ");
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops..." message:@"check your EmailID or password " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"regID is fetched and is not null %@",self.val );
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
        UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

    }
```

But when I enter wrong emailID then I get val is 0 but I navigate to home page.
what the mistake in my if condition?

Comment: I also used if([self.val isEqualToString:@"0"])  then also navigation perform.

Answer (score 0):

Create a zero value `NSString` variable and check with the value:

```
NSNumber *zeroValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
NSString *zeroString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",zeroValue];

if (self.val isEqualToString:zeroString) {
    // SHOW AN ALERT
} else {
   // else part
}
```

Comment: I want to check the value in my val variable.

Comment: if value of self.val is 0 then don't navigate. And self.val is 52 then navigation perform